# Is it possible for an on Edit function to determine whether a cell's value contains an uppercase letter or background colour changing of a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Good Afternoon Stackers!

I've got a timestamp script that I'm working on that stamps the time in a column to the right of a column where I enter a person's name. As it stands the script works and the timestamp appears when text is entered... I was hoping to further this a bit and was wondering if it is at all possible for a google script onEdit function to recognize whether or not the entered value contains an uppercase letter... or if it is possible for the onEdit to detect a change of a cells background colour.

I've searched about and have had limited success. Looking for someone to help point me in the right direction... or at least confirm whether or not such a task is possible.

Thanks in advance!!!

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
var cols = [3, 5, 7, 10, 12, 14, 17, 19, 21];
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "dd/h:mm           a")


if 
  (s !== 'SHEET 1' && s
!== 'SHEET 2' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==-1 || 
!e.range.getValue()) return;
e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(curDate);
}
```

Comment: please post the code you use presently. You can get the backgroung with range method [getBackground](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackground()) and getting the content as a string makes it easy to check the capitals with JS string methods, for example charCodeAt(position) returns the ascii code of the character.

Comment: added code to original post. Thanks Serge

Answer (score 1):

to determine whether there is a uppercase letter in the edited range you will need to usea javascript function on the event value.(if the Edit was result of a paste then you would need to use the getValue() method on the event range property). something like: Has uppercase if:

```
var val = e.range.getValue();
if(val.toString() != val.toString().toLowerCase()) \\ contains Upper
```

Changing color will not trigger and on edit event.

Comment: Thank you for the response ScampMichael. Will look start looking into a javascript function as a solution. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: added simple test for uppercase

Comment: Thanks for the test/example. Will try it out shortly. The idea I had floating around my head was for the script to search the cell for an uppercase letter and as a result change the colour of the cell's background.This way i could assign a colour to a cell dependent on how the text value is entered.

I've managed to come up with a way using conditional formatting but would love to suss out how to get it working in a script.

Thanks again!

Comment: you may want something more granular than the simple test I gave. there are many ways to evaluate strings using JavaScript. have fun exploring.

Comment: Thanks again! Needed a shove in the right direction. Hopefully i'll have come up with a solution and be back in this thread to show off my work.